# shopping list adds "quit" letter to list instead of breaking while loop and exiting program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to get this quit function to work, if I enter a lowercase "q", it works no problem. But when I enter capital "Q" it gets added to the list instead of breaking the loop.
I dont understand why it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
shopping_list = []
quit_list = 'q'
print("Shopping list")
print("When done, press 'q'")

while True:
item = input("Enter item:")  # User input item
if item == quit_list.casefold():
    break

if item in shopping_list:  # Remove item by typing same item.
    shopping_list.remove(item)
    print(shopping_list)
else:
    shopping_list.append(item)  # Add item to list
    print("{} added to list.".format(item))
    print(shopping_list)
```

print(shopping_list)

Comment: It should be `item.casefold == quit_list` - you want to ensure `item` is lowercased.

Comment: Your indentation here is broken -- your code will not run at all if there isn't an indent in the line below `while True:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shopping_list = []
quit_list = 'q'
print("Shopping list")
print("When done, press 'q'")

while True:
    item = input("Enter item:")  # User input item
    if item.casefold() == quit_list:
        break

    if item in shopping_list:  # Remove item by typing same item.
        shopping_list.remove(item)
        print(shopping_list)
    else:
        shopping_list.append(item)  # Add item to list
        print("{} added to list.".format(item))
        print(shopping_list)
print(shopping_list)
```

You want to make item lowercase, not quit_list.

Answer (score 0):

or use an explicit list of quit options:

```
shopping_list = []
quit_list = ['q','Q']
print("Shopping list")
print("When done, press 'q' or 'Q'")

while True:
    item = input("Enter item:")  # User input item
    if item in quit_list:
        break
    
    if item in shopping_list:  # Remove item by typing same item.
        shopping_list.remove(item)
        print(shopping_list)
    else:
        shopping_list.append(item)  # Add item to list
        print("{} added to list.".format(item))
        print(shopping_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with indentation and the logic is mixed up:
**if quit_list == item.casefold():**

```
shopping_list = []
quit_list = 'q'
print("Shopping list")
print("When done, press 'q'")

while True:
    item = input("Enter item:")  # User input item
    if quit_list == item.casefold():
        break

    if item in shopping_list:  # Remove item by typing same item.
        shopping_list.remove(item)
        print(shopping_list)
    else:
        shopping_list.append(item)  # Add item to list
        print("{} added to list.".format(item))
        print(shopping_list)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    item = input("Enter item:")  # User input item
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        break
```

you need to install keyboard:

```
pip install keyboard
```

Comment: This is massively overkill for no good reason; this problem can be solved without any non-default libraries.

Comment: what he said but 10x more.